# Create java script bridge for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to build a java script bridge for my app.

Through that bridge I want to call js's method, also want to call application's method from js. Can anyone help me with any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the JS function from native code,

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NAME_OF_JS_FUNCTION('ARGUMENT')",configJson]];
```

To call native function from JS,

```
window.location = "js-call:"+obj;
```

It will invoke your webview delegate method.

Comment: Thanks. I think it will work. And I also found a post with brief description to call native function from JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind waiting a couple months, check out the Javascript video at https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/.